# how to do menu item click in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, menu, vue-component, vuetify.js, menuitem-selection

I have created menu on avatar hover and also added item from item array. Now clicking on the items, have to go specific component or item. I tried this:

template:

```
 <template>
   <div>
       <v-menu offset-y open-on-hover>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                 <v-avatar color="white" size="38"  v-on="on">
                    <span class="primary--text headline">A</span>
                 </v-avatar>
              </template>
              <v-list>
                <v-list-item
                  v-for="(item, index) in items"
                  :key="index"
                  @click="selectSection(item)" >

                  <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-menu>

       </div>
 </template>
```

Script:

```
 <script>
   export default {
     data: () => ({
       items: [
         { title: 'abcd.xyz@example.com' },
         { title: 'Profile' },
         { title: 'Logout' },
         ],
      }),

     methods: {
      selectSection(item) {
       this.selectedSection = item;
      }  
    }
   </script>
```

[image]

Comment: did you have `vue-router`? and what do you mean by `go specific component or item`?
can you give me a example?

Comment: "go specific component or item" means as u can see in picture, if i click on profile it will goto profile.vue  or click on logout it will open a popup for logout. I have index.js in which routing is wriiten. @AliHosseini

Comment: so use switch-case in on your item.title

Comment: i did not understand. can u please show me @AliHosseini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use switch-case in your items like this:

```
selectSection(item) {
      switch (item.title) {
        case 'abcd.xyz@example.com':
          console.log('email')
          break
        case 'Profile':
          console.log('Profile')
          break
        case 'Logout':
          console.log('Logout')
      }
    }
```

and instead of `console.log()`s use your code for example to go to profile page instead of `console.log('Profile')` put `$router.push('/profile')`

hope it helps you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61436830/which-life-cycle-method-is-called-during-page-refreshshiftf5-in-vuejs  @Ali Hossen               Can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep your click logic together with your item data, you could do it like this. The reason I'm using `call` is that we have access to `this` (so that we can still access the Vue instance & Vuex store etc):

Template:

```html
<template>
  <v-menu bottom left>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn
        v-bind="attrs"
        v-on="on"
        color="primary"
        icon
      >
        <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>

    <v-list>
      <v-list-item
        v-for="(item, index) in items"
        :key="index"
        @click="handleClick(index)"
      >
        <v-list-item-icon>
          <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
        </v-list-item-icon>
        <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
</template>
```

Script:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { 
        title: 'Edit', 
        icon: 'mdi-pencil',
        click() {
          console.log('edit')
        }
      },
      { 
        title: 'Due Date',
        icon: 'mdi-calendar',
        click() {
          console.log('due date')
        }
      },
      { 
        title: 'Delete',
        icon: 'mdi-delete',
        click() {
          this.$store.dispatch('deleteTask', 1)
        }
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    handleClick(index) {
      this.items[index].click.call(this)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```