# which life cycle method is called during page refresh(shift+F5) in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lifecycle, page-refresh

When refresh my page, it is losing data. In my page i do a GET call in

```
  beforeMount(){
      this.getUserProfile()
    },
```

and when i am refreshing the page, the user profile data are lost. 
So which life cycle method is called during page refresh?? or during page refresh where i have to call getProfile() method?

getUserProfile:

```
 getUserProfile() {
    let flag = 1;

  axios
    .get("/api/user")
    .then(response => {
        let data = response.data;

       if (flag == 1) {

          this.fname = data.user.first_name;
          this.lname = data.user.last_name;
          this.email =  data.user.email;

        }else {
            Vue.$toast.error(data.message, {
            position: 'top-right'
            });
        }
     // })
      // .catch(err => {
      //   Vue.$toast.error(err, {
      //   position: 'top-right'
      //   });

       });

 },
```

Comment: The same method as when the page is opened the first time. With the exception of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation , JS is totally unaware of refreshes. The page is just loaded, with some assets being served from cache if they were cached. You can call getProfile in any lifecycle you like (`mounted` or earlier), it will be completed asynchronously at roughly the same time.

Comment: did you use SSR (server side rendering) ?

Comment: no @AliHosseini

Comment: As I know before mount is not calling in ssr mode by the way try to replace before mount with mounted and check is it working or not